# Combining BundleDbPersistenceManager with FsBlobStore does not work as expected

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

I have a problem with programmatically initialised **BundleDbPersistenceManager** with a local blob store. I can verify that this blob store is initialised as **FSBlobStore**. Problem starts with **BundleDbPersistenceManager** doesn't not respecting the following values;

```
bundleDbPersistenceManager.setExternalBLOBs(true);
bundleDbPersistenceManager.setMinBlobSize("10");
```

I also initialise the bundle with `bundleDbPersistenceManager#init` method which seems to be the correct way to do.

After this point I am restoring the backup however, all the data ends up in the db and the created blob folder directory is empty. I am wondering what would be the reason of **bundleDbPersistenceManager** not the respect this blog store presence at all? I am currently using 2.8 version however, i tried to upgrade to the latest version (2.12.1) which also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't manage to find what was the problem with the Low Level API, however, when I used RepositoryCopier my problems were all gone. I can say its more stable and I haven't encountered the problem above (DataStore's are not respected)

https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/RepositoryCopier.html